# Creating Python Pinger - Sockets

Tags: python

Ok, changed everything to try and ask a more specific question.

I have two methods. doOnePing was my creation to use sendOnePing, which was written for me in an aid to understand sockets better.

I am trying to understand if I am creating the socket correctly within doOnePing, I believe I am, but I am not sure if I am missing something specific or could do it better.

Thanks

```
def sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, ID):
    # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)

    myChecksum = 0
    # Make a dummy header with a 0 checksum
    # struct -- Interpret strings as packed binary data
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
    # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
    myChecksum = checksum(header + data)

    # Get the right checksum, and put in the header
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        # Convert 16-bit integers from host to network  byte order
        myChecksum = htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
    else:
        myChecksum = htons(myChecksum)

    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    packet = header + data

    mySocket.sendto(packet, (destAddr, 1))  # AF_INET address must be tuple, not str


# Both LISTS and TUPLES consist of a number of objects
# which can be referenced by their position number within the object.

def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):
    icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")
    # SOCK_RAW For more details:   http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw

    # Fill in start

    mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    #Fill in end


    myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF  # Return the current process i
    sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
    delay = receiveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)

    mySocket.close()
    return delay
```

Comment: You're asking a whole lot of questions here. You need to split these up so they're answerable. Find a small SPECIFIC area in which you need help, then show us that

Comment: Also, if you're new with Python, try working out simple things, instead of going into comprehensive and as you say confusing initiatives.

Comment: Ok yea I understand that...I guess I am pretty confused in general. Would it be better if I asked a specific question about one specific method?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I understand the concepts, I am just trying to learn the language as I go, much of this makes sense!

Comment: Changed everything, does that help with what I am trying to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using scapy instead to ping. You can easily get scapy by running:

```
pip install scapy
```

using this you would be able to ping much more easily